# Git credential helper doesn't work on windows subsystem for linux

Tags: git, github, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I am using Ubuntu in WSL on Windows 10 and I have git installed in WSL and use it regularly. I have a very annoying problem where I try to cache my github credentials so I don't have to constantly enter my username/password when commiting but it doesn't work. I follow the exact instructions provided by github verbaitim. First I enter:

```
git config --global credential.helper cache
```

then I enter:

```
git config --global credential.helper 'cache --timeout=2629800'
```

but nothing happens, I still have to constantly enter my github username and password

EDIT:

To clarify I'm doing all this through the bash terminal on ubuntu wsl and I am not using the windows version of git. I am using the version of git that was included in ubuntu. All these commands I entered are linux commands.

Comment: When you're having this problem, are you using the WSL Git via the WSL command line or Git in a Win32 program?  Also, I take it you're entering this at the WSL command line (bash or similar)?

Comment: I am using git in the wsl command line, not the windows version of git and all these commands are entered in the ubuntu wsl bash terminal

Comment: https://github.com/microsoft/WSL/issues/134 maybe the reason

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Probably the reason is incomplete support for Unix domain sockets in WSL

You can use instead the windows credential manager: https://www.edwardthomson.com/blog/git_credential_manager_with_windows_subsystem_for_linux.html

From the link, here is how to enable it:

> git config --global credential.helper "/mnt/c/Program\ Files/Git/mingw64/libexec/git-core/git-credential-manager.exe"

Comment: Thank you this solution works perfectly! Hopefully with future updates to WSL they'll get the Unix domain sockets working and people won't need to install git on windows

Comment: For me, the command was a bit different ```git config --global credential.helper "/mnt/c/Program\\ Files/Git/mingw64/libexec/git-core/git-credential-wincred.exe"```

Answer (score 1):

You could use SSH instead of HTTP. Once set up, you only have to input your SSH password upon booting WSL.

After trying several methods on WSL 2, this is what worked for me. I chose to host my SSH keys within WSL instead of Windows.

Follow GitHub's guide for [adding a new SSH key to your GitHub account](https://docs.github.com/en/github/authenticating-to-github/adding-a-new-ssh-key-to-your-github-account) if you haven't done so already. Be sure to select "Linux" (for WSL) near the top of this page.

Install [keychain](https://funtoo.org/Keychain):

```
sudo apt install keychain
```

Then add the following line to your shell's configuration file (likely `~/.bashrc` or `~/.zshrc`):

```
eval `keychain --quiet --eval --agents ssh id_rsa`
```

Now you will only have to enter your password when booting WSL!

Thank you Birk Holland for [this article](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/commandline/sharing-ssh-keys-between-windows-and-wsl-2/) on sharing SSH keys between Windows and WSL 2.